# Where Can I Find Good Ship Plans?

Tags: online-resources, vehicles, historical-settings

I need a variety of ship plans - not surface deck plans, and not side views, but actual interior arrangements of various sorts of vessels - orlop deck, cable locker, that sort of thing. They are pretty hard to find. Any resources out there? Actual plans only, please, not game-related material. And it has to be a useful size, 1024x768 or bigger.

I'd love to see anything smaller than the Titanic, but bonus points if you can point me to an early twentieth century tramp steamship.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for **real-world research,** only incidentally related to RPGs and unrelated to and not benefiting from RPG expertise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The interface is absolutely terrible, but [The Historic American Engineering Record](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/collection/hh/) has a maritime project. When it has what you want, it's absolutely brilliant - see for example [this drawing](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/cgi-bin/displayPhoto.pl?path=/pnp/habshaer/ca/ca1500/ca1507/sheet&topImages=00003a.gif&topLinks=00003r.tif,00003a.tif&title=&displayProfile=0) (one of several) of [The Steam Tug HERCULES](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/collection/hh/item/CA1507/). You can try searching by type of ship or you can [search for "maritime"](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/search/?q=maritime&co=hh), which seems to turn up a number of ships. When you get your results list, if the inventory summary includes "drawings" you're most likely in luck.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. There are some real gems in there, it's a shame they can be so hard to find. Searching for USS turns up a few more.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled across a list of ferry plans... http://www.hhvferry.com/deckplans

Comment: Very cool find.

Answer (score 3):

Online resources you might find moderately useful for the tramp steamer are:

[Model Ship World](http://modelshipworld.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=5567&postdays=0&postorder=asc&&start=0)

[Tramp Steamers](http://home.earthlink.net/~djackson24/TrampSteamer2.pdf)

- [SS Semiramis](http://www.louislamourgreatadventure.com/PongaJimMerchantMarine3.htm)

*note: I could not find anything at the size you requested. You are right about the lack of material which matches your request.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful~

Answer (score 3):

I gladly volunteer [my little collection of ships](http://www.pa-mar.net/rpg/pulp/vehicles/vehicles_intro.html) (and other vehicles) for my currently defunct Pulp campaign.

I am slowly redesigning the site, so if someone reaches this comment in the future I suggest to start from [an higher-level entry point](http://pa-mar.net/Main/Hobbies/Games.html).

Also, if you find the 115-foot Freighter close enough to your requirements, please contact me (there is an email link at the bottom of the second link page). I may be able to dig up some deckplans.

---

See [this page](http://christinayoung.com/pages/diving/biancac/biancac.htm) for "Blanca C" a ship built in 1939. There is a full story and deckplans too.

The [Nothland](http://greatergreaterwashington.org/post.cgi?id=3089) was built by the Harlan & Hollingsworth Corp., Wilmington, Del., in 1911 for the Norfolk and Washington Steamboat Company. Like the Southland, she transported passengers and freight between Washington and Norfolk.

The [Stockholm](http://www.salship.se/stock.asp) of 1948 (look for a deckplan link around middle of the page)

Or just put "steam deckplan" in google and select "images" from the results...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you can find what you need there, but [Ships Nostalgia](http://www.shipsnostalgia.com/guides/Main_Page) has a lot of useful stuff, including galleries, a discussion board, and more. Probably a good place to go asking for this sort of thing. Free to join.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a exactly a plan, but it should be a good supplement to any plans that get dug up and is full of awesome to boot: [H.M.S. Temeraire 3/4-view labeled cutaway](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2010/01/22/article-0-07F5F514000005DC-604_964x763.jpg). And here's the [original article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1245180/HMS-Invincible-Inside-battle-ship-famous-Turner-fighting-Temeraire.html), in case the direct link doesn't work.

I'll keep looking for a proper source of plans in the meantime.

Comment: The cutaway seems to be more common for older ships - I found a lovely one of HMS Leopard, too.

Answer (score 1):

[The Ferris wooden cargo ships of World War I](http://cocatrez.net/Water/FerrisShips/FerrisShips.html) page has an excellent set of documents on an immediately post WW1 design (Ferris class), and lesser details of some other vessels.

Comment: +1 as well for the excellent bibliography at the end of the page.